# Restart delayed job inside it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I need to restart current DJ if some condition happens.

```
if cond1
  #process
elsif
  #here I need to restart
else
  raise
end
```

I didn't write custom job for it, I just use `smth.delay.task`. So I can run it again calling `self.delay.task` again, but I don't like it, cause this doesn't wait: when a job fails it is performed again with a delay. If I run it custom, it starts almost immediately. So it creates kind of spam.

Is there a way to implement what I need?

Comment: Are you trying to restart the job or the worker?

Comment: Exactly the job. I just need to run the same job but several seconds later